# Two seamingly identical loops but different outcomes

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a loop that finds the adjacent value based on a looped additem list combobox in userform. First looped code works just perfect. second doesnt find its value.

I've tried changing formatting in the cell where the value is stored. i've tried to switch the userform box with the working one. That makes them both malfunction.

```
'Works without a problem

Private Sub REQUESTED_Change()
    i = 1
    kto = FORM.REQUESTED
    Do While (Worksheets("DATA").Cells(i, 1) <> "")
        i = i + 1
        If Worksheets("DATA").Cells(i, 1) = kto Then
            DEPARTEMENT.Text = Worksheets("DATA").Cells(i, 2)
        End If
    Loop
End Sub

'Doesn't work. It loops with the correct value, but doesnt find itself

Private Sub CUSTNR_Change()
    i4 = 1
    kSto = FORM.CUSTNR
    Do While (Worksheets("DATA").Cells(i4, 6) <> "")
        i4 = i4 + 1
        If Worksheets("DATA").Cells(i4, 6) = kSto Then
            NAZWA.Text = Worksheets("DATA").Cells(i4, 7)
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

It should loop based on the value typed/listed in the userform combobox, find the row its in, and based on that i value, get the adjacent value in the cell next to it in the same row.

Comment: You could use `Range.Find` instead of looping row by row - but to be honest, it's impossible to help without some sample data or a screenshot to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Without a [mcve] it is hard to do any more than guess. There is some difference between the two scenarios, but you have given no information about what these scenarios are. Your question is basically -- I have some similar code which, when run on data that you don't have access to, behave differently.

Comment: You can get problems using variable names that look like cell addresses. You shouldn't but it sometimes happens. Try renaming i4 to something else